# Retrieving most recent purchase data from database

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query retrieving the latest record. My table is shown below.

```
|cname|fname |date     |total|
|tony |bun   |10-8-2015|$0.80|
|tony |lamb  |10-8-2015|$0.80|
|tony |cheese|10-8-2015|$0.80|
|tony |spicy |10-8-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |crispy|10-9-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |beef  |10-9-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |normal|10-9-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |normal|10-9-2015|$0.80|
```

This is my SQL query:

```
$query1="select fname, total, cname, max_date = max(date) from purchase
group by cname";
```

I want the result to look like the one below:

```
|cname|fname |date     |total|
|sue  |crispy|10-9-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |beef  |10-9-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |normal|10-9-2015|$0.80|
|sue  |normal|10-9-2015|$0.80|
```

My problem is that I want to retrieve the latest data, but it keeps giving a data-not-found error. My data XAMPP structure for date is (date).

Comment: `select fname, total, cname, date from purchase where date = (select max(date) from purchase)`

Comment: it does work but it retrieve all the data that have been inserted today. How can i specify into just example one buyer?..sorry i am not good with my english

Comment: "My data xampp structure for date is (date)" Really? It doesn't look like it! And don't store '$'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following!

```
$query1 = "select fname, total, cname, max(date) from purchase as maxdate
           group by cname limit 1;
```

Comment: Isn't it missing an ending quote (`"`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub query for this in which you retrieve the max dates by cname and fname (based on your output, you need the fname as well) and join this back to the original table:

```
select t.* from table t
inner join (
      select cname, fname, max(date) as mdate from table group by cname, fname) t2
on t.fname=t2.fname and t.cname=t2.cname and t.date=t2.mdate
```

Comment: it display all the date including previous date from a month ago as well